# Create an exe with jar file AND resources

Tags: java, resources, exe

Is there a way to create an exe that includes a resources folder inside it? I am looking for something like mac's Application bundle package things. I also want the ability to write and read from files within the resources folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you build the jar with the resources inside it, then you can use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap it as an executable (for free!).

You'll still need the JRE, but otherwise it will act just like a normal .exe.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge it will still just be a .zip file with a .exe extension, so yes. Why not test it yourself?

Comment: Oh, actually, that makes sense. I don't know of any way to write to an executable that's already running. Of course, that's largely because I've never tried.