# How can i Make an .exe file from jar file

Tags: java, dependency-injection, exe

I developed a system using jdk 6. then i want to deploy that system to all kind of users(windows, linux). and also i want to create . exe file to install inside the client machine. this process should check whether there exists java(compatible version) inside the client machine. if there is not java inside the machine then installation process should provides facility to install it.and also software used to do that should be freely available.
thanks in advance.

Comment: But .exe will be supported only in Windows Platform ri8?

Comment: Please check this link:
http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/09/convert-java-jar-file-to-exe

Comment: I don't mean to be mean, but this the third time I've seen such a question in two days.  Having said that, I use exe4j.  You will need to pay for it, but it does most of what you asked, at least one Windows.

Comment: This is a very common question.  You should search this site for other answers.

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473194/create-an-exe-with-jar-file-and-resources  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875587/create-exe-from-jar-file-using-build-xml

Comment: If the app. has a GUI the answer is `deployJava.js` + [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Here's [one duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/147181/778118)... and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4330936/778118)... and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2272107/778118)... and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10872204/778118)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Basically you will need to write a NSIS script to do the following

1. Check if JAVA exists. [Depending on 32 or 64 bit machine you need to check different node]
2. Get the java path
3. Run the command java -jar XXXX

There are many sample scripts available on NSIS site. Let me know if you need more help. I will send you sample script.

Answer (score 1):

there are few tools available for this. google for "JarToExe", "advanceInstaller".

REF: [Convert Jar file to EXE executable](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-jar-to-exe-executable-jar-file-to-exe-converting/)